# How to make plotly graph fit to div in HTML?

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, plotly

I have created a plotly graph in python and would like to display it on my `HTML` page. The problem is that the graph does not seem to fit the `div` propertly. Here is what I mean:

[image]

I would like it to scale based on the screen size to fit into the first column, but no matter what i do in `iframe`, the size of the graph itsesf remains constant. How can that be fixed?

P.S. I am unable to change the python code, so I am looking for the solution in `HTML`, but it would be interesting to hear how to fix this in the future in `python`

Here is the code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <iframe id="igraph" scrolling="no" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%" seamless="seamless" src="report_graph_2.html"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And [here](https://www.sendgb.com/rNetzivZKMk) is a full website if you need to see the code for the plotly graph.